# Run SQL Script within a table/string and output results to file

Tags: sql, sql-server, recursion, ssis-2012

I need to run the SQL scripts that are held in a report configuration table and output the results as .csv or .xls files in a desired folder with a file name that is also specified within the report config table.

An example of the table is as per script below with column A being the desired file name to be created and Column B contains the script that will be executed.

Ideally I require a script that i can drop into a Stored Proc that will run down each row in the table and export and create each rows results as a separate file in a desired folder.

I think it needs to be a recursive query but I'm really not sure where to start, any advice or help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: So it was suggested that I use SSIS, can this be done with the existing toolbox items or would I need to write a script to do this? There are hundreds of SQL scripts in the table so efficiency is key!

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test_Table_PS](
  [File_Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
  [Script_To_Run] [nvarchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Test_Table_PS] ([File_Name], [Script_To_Run]) 
VALUES (N'Report_1', N'Select * FROM FRED')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Test_Table_PS] ([File_Name], [Script_To_Run]) 
VALUES (N'Report_2', N'Select * FROM BOB')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Test_Table_PS] ([File_Name], [Script_To_Run]) 
VALUES (N'Report_3', N'Select * FROM DAVE')
GO
```

Comment: You should try this using SSIS.

Comment: @Abhishek That would probably be a good idea! Though is it possible to loop through the rows in the table using the available toolbox items or would this need to be scripted?

Comment: it will be possible only through script task. As I feel the query that you have provided will yield in variable number of columns with different data types, so in this case it will not be possible to make them work in `Data Flow Task` and `Excel Destination`. If they result in same number of columns with same data type then I guess it will be possible provided we setup the `column` in the `source`-`destination` mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd probably be best using a `WHILE` loop or a `CURSOR` for this operation. Although a `WHILE` loop requires an ID field. Something like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test_Table_PS](
  [File_Name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
  [Script_To_Run] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
  [Report_ID] INT IDENTITY(1,1)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Test_Table_PS] ([File_Name], [Script_To_Run]) 
VALUES (N'Report_1', N'Select * FROM FRED')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Test_Table_PS] ([File_Name], [Script_To_Run]) 
VALUES (N'Report_2', N'Select * FROM BOB')
GO

INSERT [dbo].[Test_Table_PS] ([File_Name], [Script_To_Run]) 
VALUES (N'Report_3', N'Select * FROM DAVE')
GO

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SCRIPT NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @FILENAME NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @ID INT

SET @ID = 1

WHILE @ID <= (SELECT MAX(REPORT_ID) FROM [dbo].[Test_Table_PS])
    BEGIN
        SELECT @SCRIPT = SCRIPT_TO_RUN FROM [dbo].[Test_Table_PS] WHERE @ID = REPORT_ID
        SELECT @FILENAME = FILENAME FROM [dbo].[Test_Table_PS] WHERE @ID = REPORT_ID

        SET @SQL = 'BCP "'+@SCRIPT+'" QUERYOUT "'+@FILENAME+'" -T -c -t,'
        PRINT @SQL
        EXEC (@SQL)

        SET @ID = @ID + 1
    END
```

Don't forget to add the filepath to your filenames.

Comment: Thanks, this works great for producing the BCP script but it cannot be executed in SQL Server it needs to be run in the command line. This will help though to make up an SSIS package when then runs these in command prompt.